# Django: uso de etiquetas en los Template dentro de Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, api, django-templates

Estoy haciendo un rastreador de direcciones IP con `Django`, estoy utilizando para crear el mapa la **API de google maps** y para la geolocalizacion [esta API](https://ip-api.com/docs/api:json), quiero que muestre en el mapa mi localización automáticamente cuando abra la página, y si es otra dirección IP pues la localización en el mapa de esa dirección IP,

El problema es que **no sé como integrar código de `Django` en** `Javascript` para las coordenadas,o no sé si hay otra forma de hacerlo mas sencilla, o con otra APIs.

En el archivo Javascript  en la variable **coord** quiero pasar los parámetro del json **lat** y **longit**, para que  la **lat** y **lng** de Javascript lo tome.

Archivos:

view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

def home(request):
    response = requests.get('http://ip-api.com/json/')
    geodata = response.json()
    data= {
            'ip': geodata['query'],
            'country': geodata['country'],
            'timezone':geodata['timezone'],
            'lat': geodata['lat'],
            'longit': geodata['lon'],
            'isp':geodata['isp'],
            'api_key':'Mi Api key de google maps',
        }

    return render(request, 'geolocationip/home.html', data)
```

script.js:

```
function initMap(){
    //var lat="{{ lat }}";
    //var lng="{{ longit }}";
    console.log(coord)
    var coord = {lat: ? , lng: ?};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
      zoom: 10,
      center: coord
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coord,
      map: map
    });
  }
```

home.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
    
{% block content %}
<h1 id="ip">IP Address Tracker</h1>

<form method="get"id="form">
    <input><button>Search</button>
</form>

  <div id="card">
    <p>Your ip address is <strong>{{ ip }}</strong>, and you are probably in <strong>{{ country }}</strong> right now, and 
    <strong>{{timezone}}</strong> and <strong>{{isp}}</strong></p>
  </div>  

<div id="map"></div>

{% endblock content %}


{% block js %}

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{ api_key }}&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"defer></script>

{% endblock js %}
```

Así va quedando:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Revisando el código que has publicado no encuentro donde hayas importado el script donde está tu función de javascript, de igual manera aunque lo importes, sugieron que agregues esa función directamente a tu template home.html dentro de otro tag de  abajo de donde estás importando la api de googlemaps

```
{% block js %}
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{ api_key }}&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"defer></script>
<script>
function initMap() {
    var lat={{ lat|safe }};
    var lng={{ longit|safe }};
    console.log(coord)
    var coord = {lat: lat , lng: lng};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
      zoom: 10,
      center: coord
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coord,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
{% endblock js %}
```

De esta manera como tu script está en el template tiene acceso directo a los datos que enviaste desde la vista en tu variable 'data', como verás en el código más arriba ahora ya podemos definir las variables de lat y lng para tu mapa, y lo hice con el filtro de safe.

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido añadiéndolo en el Template directamente.

Comment: El filtro safe para que sirve específicamente? para que los datos estén seguros no?     Otra pregunta no estoy seguro si esa es manera mas optima y segura? es decir los datos de direcciones IP, lat y lng se encuentran seguros colocando directamente en el Template?

Comment: Y en verdad no sé si decir que sea óptima o insegura, mover tu código javascript en un archivo separado del template no hace que el código no sea accesible en el lado del cliente, lo que sí se podría criticar es que quizás no sea una buena práctica para el mantenimiento de código.

Comment: En verdad lo que haces a poner el filtro safe es marcar el contenido como seguro, o sino django lo que hace es 'escaparlo', en verdad es menos seguro si no sabes que estás haciendo, si quieres puedes quitarlo pero luego quizás te toque hacer algo como encerrarlo entre comillas para que se convierta en una cadena en el javascript y luego parsearlo a un float, o json o el tipo de datos que necesites, pero terminarías con lo mismo.